# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.config.AopConfigUtils

Tags: java, spring

Today when I start my app, shows error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.config.AopConfigUtils
```

I am check my project and found it already contains `Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:2.5.7` dependencies. what should I do to fix this problem? Should I add this class AopConfigUtils? I am sure I did not mix version because all the version management by the `org.springframework.boot` gradle plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Check whether this JAR is present in the application classpath. ...
If that JAR is already present in the classpath, make sure the classpath is not overridden.

And please check if you are not mixing the version.

Answer (score 1):

Try alternative for mvn clean install. Clean cache in Intellij if previous command doesn’t help.

Comment: I am use gradle to management the dependencies.@Marek Borecki I already tried this way.

Answer (score 1):

In maven version for spring boot starters are always skipped. Try remove version number from dependency.